# How do I create a mutation on a nested object with GraphQL?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, graphql

I'm trying to create a graphql mutation to update an object field with an array of other objects.  Here is my schema:

```
    type Guide {
      _id: ID!
      first_name: String!
      last_name: String
      email: String!
      phone: String!
      creator: User!
    }

    input GuideInput {
      _id: ID!
      first_name: String!
      last_name: String
      email: String!
      phone: String!
    }

    type Trip {
      _id: ID!
      name: String!
      description: String
      location: String
      start_date: String
      start_time: String
      duration: Int
      creator: User!
      guides: [Guide!]
      guests: [Guest!]
    }

    input TripInput {
      name: String
      description: String
      location: String
      start_date: String
      start_time: String
      duration: Int
      guides: [GuideInput]
    }

    type RootQuery {
      trips: [Trip!]
      guides: [Guide!]
    }

    type RootMutation {
      updateTrip(tripId: ID!, tripInput: TripInput): Trip
      deleteTrip(tripId: ID!): Trip
      createGuide(guideInput: GuideInput): Guide
      deleteGuide(guideId: ID!): Guide
    }

    schema {
      query: RootQuery
      mutation: RootMutation
    }
```

And my query looks like this:

```
const requestBody = {
      query: `
        mutation {
          updateTrip(
            tripId: "${tripId}",
            tripInput: {
              guides: ${guides}
            }
          ) {
            guides {
              first_name
              last_name
            }
          }
        }
      `
    }
```

The error I'm getting when I execute this request is:

```
Expected type GuideInput, found object.
Expected type GuideInput, found Object.
```

I am passing an array of objects into the mutation that is the same shape as the GuideInput object so I'm stumped. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot pass your inputs into your query this way. When you use template literals with placeholders, the result of the expression inside the placeholder (`${guides}`) is treated like a string. If `guides` is an Object (which it is, if it is an Array), it has `toString()` called on it, which results in the string `[object Object]`. You end up with a string that looks like:

```
tripInput: {
  guides: [object Object]
}
```

The correct way to substitute values inside your query is to use variables and avoid using placeholders altogether. Your `requestBody` would then look something like this:

```js
const requestBody = {
  query: `
    mutation SomeMutationName($tripId: ID!, $guides: [GuideInput]) {
     updateTrip(
        tripId: $tripId
        tripInput: {
          guides: $guides
        }
      ) {
        guides {
          first_name
          last_name
        }
      }
    }
  `,
  variables: {
    tripId,
    guides,
  },
}
```

See [the official tutorial](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables) and [the spec](https://facebook.github.io/graphql/June2018/#sec-Language.Variables) for more details about how to use variables.

Comment: I would also highly recommend using a client like [Apollo](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/apollo-client.html) instead of putting the requests together yourself.

Comment: Awesome - worked like a charm.  I am trying to get a firm understanding of how GraphQL works before using something like Apollo.  Thanks for your help Daniel!